# Select based on specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

*If someone could update the title to better reflect my question that would be much appreciated. I think I've struggled to find the answer somewhat because I don't know the right search terms.*

> If I have the following values in a table:
>
> ```
> TableID      TableSensitivity
> -----------------------------
> 1            aSensitivity
> 1            aRevision
> 2            bRevision
> 3            cRevision
> 3            cSensitivity
> ```
>
> How can I filter the values containing "Revision" *only* for each TableID where the is
>   already a value containing "Sensitivity". This is the expected output:
>
> ```
> TableID      TableSensitivity
> -----------------------------
> 1            aSensitivity
> 2            bRevision
> 3            cSensitivity
> ```

Here's an example setup:

```
DECLARE  @Example TABLE (TableID INT, TableSensitivity VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @Example(TableID, TableSensitivity) VALUES (1, 'aSensitivity')
INSERT INTO @Example(TableID, TableSensitivity) VALUES (1, 'aRevision')
INSERT INTO @Example(TableID, TableSensitivity) VALUES (2, 'bRevision')
INSERT INTO @Example(TableID, TableSensitivity) VALUES (3, 'cSensitivity')
INSERT INTO @Example(TableID, TableSensitivity) VALUES (3, 'cRevision')
```

I've tried using CASE to determine the rows with sensitivities and figured that I could use a MAX to filter, but couldn't get it working:

```
SELECT TableID
     , TableSensitivity
     , CASE WHEN TableSensitivity LIKE '%Sensitivity' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'SomeKey' 
FROM @Example
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Looks like SQL Server. Please label.

Comment: @WEI_DBA, thanks -- done

Comment: I would try splitting the `TableSensitivity` into 2 columns. The first letter and the rest. Then you could control the grouping and search for the sensitivities.

Comment: Just to clarify, where there's only one letter before "Sensitivity" or "Revision" here (i.e. "a","b","c"), the actual case has variable number of letters before.

Comment: Ok, but still, those letters before the `keyword`have meaning and theoretically could be split out for better control.

Comment: That's a good point. thanks @WEI_DBA

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT TableID
     , TableSensitivity
FROM @Example e1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @Example e2
    WHERE e1.TableID=e2.TableID
    AND e2.TableSensitivity LIKE '%Sensitivity'
    AND e1.TableSensitivity LIKE '%Revision'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it gives me exactly the output I need. Now I just need to read up on `WHERE NOT EXISTS` :)

Answer (score 2):

this gets rid of the rows in `@Example` and returns your expected result. it can be modified and worked into your query if needed:

```
DELETE
FROM    @Example
WHERE   TableID IN
        (
            SELECT  TableID
            FROM    @Example
            WHERE   TableSensitivity LIKE '%Sensitivity%'
        )
        AND TableSensitivity LIKE '%Revision%'

SELECT  *
FROM    @Example
```

Comment: The question suggests that the OP really wants a `SELECT` (given that this is the example code in the question).

Comment: Well, you could argue that OP did say `remove` and not `filter`. :-)

Comment: when i posted my reply (and as of right now), the question states "How can I remove the values...", so that's the reason for the `DELETE`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I did say *remove* without realising the connotation. Ideally SELECT is preferred, but thank you for this -- it would do the trick if I put my values into a table variables.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved using the FIRST_VALUE function (for SQL Server 2012 and over)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TableID, 
    FIRST_VALUE(TableSensitivity) OVER (PARTITION BY TableID ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN  TableSensitivity LIKE '%Sensitivity' THEN 1 
            WHEN TableSensitivity LIKE '%Revision' THEN 2 
            ELSE 3 END) as TableSensitivity
FROM @Example
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I completely misunderstood the question.  I see, you want a prioritization query.  One simple method is:

```
select e.*
from @example e
where e.TableSensitivity like '%Sensitivity'
union all
select e.*
from @example e
where e.TableSensitivity like '%Revision' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from @example e2
                  where e2.tableId = e.tableId and
                        e2.TableSensitivity like '%Sensitivity'
                 );
```

A more general approach uses `row_number()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by tableId
                                order by case when e.TableSensitivity like '%Sensitivity' then 1 when e.TableSensitivity like '% Revision' then 2 else 3 end
                               ) as seqnum
      from @example e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Neither queries give the intended output.

Comment: In the first query, change the `AND` to an `OR` in the `Having` statement. That should fix the first query.

Comment: The second query block returns all the entries from the table.

Comment: @Simon . . . I really misunderstood the question.  Oddly, I don't think the other answers have the best solutions, so I have edited the answer rather than deleting it.